# Nested type as template parameter of base class

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible?

example:

```
template<class T>
class A {};

class B : public A<B::C>
{
public:
  struct C {};
};
```

Problem is that B::C is undeclared identifier (which is obvious why) and I don't know how to make it work.
In summary: Can B derive from A with template parameter set to C?

Comment: Suggesting a workaround: Move `C` out of `B`, then `typedef` it inside `B` if you need it to be a sub-type. [Either by defining a new "C" for each "B"-ish type that is used like that](http://ideone.com/8EdO0V) or alternatively even [this "double-CRTP" solution.](http://ideone.com/1YTUAp)

Comment: (In my second workaround, you're supposed to implement `B::C` as a specialization `C<B>`.)

Comment: First one is exactly what I did, but now I like second more.

Comment: Glad I could help. Well, I guess it depends on the overall design / use case which approach fits better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. `B` is incomplete at this point, because you have not yet defined the class it should inherit from. Thus it is not possible to reference `B::C` here (nested classes/structs depend on the complete definition of their enclosing class/struct, since the nested type could and often does depend on the definition of the enclosing one).